# Почему svg анимация не отображает событие нажатия кнопки?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, svg, css-animation

Я создал некоторую анимацию SVG, и  добавил её для своего веб-приложения, теперь, когда я нажимаю кнопку «Add Score» после того, как  отобразилась эта анимация, та же страница перемещается наверх (как в случае с текстом Facebook delight animation-im вложенный образец изображения)

(посмотрите и щелкните сниппет, анимация уже отображается - без нажатия кнопки, но я не хочу этого делать)

Во-вторых, - я хочу при повторном нажатии кнопки   воспроизвести эту же анимацию и после перенаправления следующей страницы,

анимация не работает, пожалуйста, помогите мне исправить это.

```css
svg{
  background: transparent;

  padding-top:-20px;
}

.conf0{fill:#FC6394;}
.conf1{fill:#EF3C8A;}
.conf2{fill:#5ADAEA;}
.conf3{fill:#974CBE;}
.conf4{fill:#3CBECD;}
.conf5{fill:#813BBE;}
.conf6{fill:#F9B732;}
.conf7{display:none;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.conf8{fill:none;stroke:#F9B732;stroke-width:9;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}


.confetti-cone{
  transform-origin: 200px 50px;
  animation:confetti-cone1 1.2s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes confetti-cone1{
  0%{
    transform:translate(40px, 95px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  15%{
    transform:translate(10px, 145px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1.1, 0.85);

  }
  100%{
    transform:translate(40px, 105px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
}

#yellow-strip {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#F9B732;
  stroke-width:9;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  animation: confdash 1.2s ease infinite;
}


@keyframes confdash {
  0%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(-30px, 30px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  2%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(-30px, 30px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  35%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:900;
    transform:translate(-2px, 0px);
    opacity:1;
  }

  85%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    transform:translate(1px, -5px);
    opacity:1;
  }
  90%{
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    transform:translate(2px, -8px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(2px, -8px);
    opacity:0;
  }
}



#conf-a{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confa 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confa {
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  15%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(25px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  80%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(33px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(37px, -23px) scale(0.5)rotate(230deg);
  }
}


#conf-b{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confb 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confb {
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  12%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(25px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(33px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(37px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(240deg);
  }
}

#conf-c{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confc 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confc {
  0%{
    opacity:0.7;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  18%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(5px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(13px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(17px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(230deg);
  }
}

#conf-d{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confd 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confd {
  0%{
    opacity:0.7;
    transform: translate(-20px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  18%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(-5px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(-8px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-10px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(230deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="footer-tab">
  <!--button-->
  <div class="crtnewgrp-btn">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <a href="addacore" style="text-decoration: none;"> <div class="p-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Add score</button></div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!--/button-->
</div>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 1200 800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 800;" xml:space="preserve">
         <g class="confetti-cone">
             <path class="conf0" d="M131.5,172.6L196,343c2.3,6.1,11,6.1,13.4,0l65.5-170.7L131.5,172.6z"/>
             <path class="conf1" d="M131.5,172.6L196,343c2.3,6.1,11,6.1,13.4,0l6.7-17.5l-53.6-152.9L131.5,172.6z"/>

                <path class="conf2" d="M274.2,184.2c-1.8,1.8-4.2,2.9-7,2.9l-129.5,0.4c-5.4,0-9.8-4.4-9.8-9.8c0-5.4,4.4-9.8,9.9-9.9l129.5-0.4
                    c5.4,0,9.8,4.4,9.8,9.8C277,180,275.9,182.5,274.2,184.2z"/>
                <polygon class="conf3" points="231.5,285.4 174.2,285.5 143.8,205.1 262.7,204.7          "/>
                <path class="conf4" d="M166.3,187.4l-28.6,0.1c-5.4,0-9.8-4.4-9.8-9.8c0-5.4,4.4-9.8,9.9-9.9l24.1-0.1c0,0-2.6,5-1.3,10.6
                    C161.8,183.7,166.3,187.4,166.3,187.4z"/>
                <ellipse transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -89.8523 231.0278)" class="conf2" cx="233.9" cy="224" rx="5.6" ry="5.6"/>
                <path class="conf5" d="M143.8,205.1l5.4,14.3c6.8-2.1,14.4-0.5,19.7,4.8c7.7,7.7,7.6,20.1-0.1,27.8c-1.7,1.7-3.7,3-5.8,4l11.1,29.4
                    l27.7,0l-28-80.5L143.8,205.1z"/>
                <path class="conf2" d="M169,224.2c-5.3-5.3-13-6.9-19.7-4.8l13.9,36.7c2.1-1,4.1-2.3,5.8-4C176.6,244.4,176.6,231.9,169,224.2z"/>
                <ellipse transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -119.0946 221.1253)" class="conf6" cx="207.4" cy="254.3" rx="11.3" ry="11.2"/>
        </g>

            <rect x="113.7" y="135.7" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -99.5348 209.1582)" class="conf7" width="178" height="178"/>
        <line class="conf7" x1="76.8" y1="224.7" x2="328.6" y2="224.7"/>
        <polyline class="conf7" points="202.7,350.6 202.7,167.5 202.7,98.9  "/>
          <!-- here comes the confettis-->

        <circle class="conf2" id="conf-b" cx="195.2" cy="232.6" r="5.1"/>
        <circle class="conf0" id="conf-b" cx="230.8" cy="219.8" r="5.4"/>
        <circle class="conf0" id="conf-c" cx="178.9" cy="160.4" r="4.2"/>
        <circle class="conf6" id="conf-d"cx="132.8" cy="123.6" r="5.4"/>
        <circle class="conf0" id="conf-d" cx="151.9" cy="105.1" r="5.4"/>

        <path class="conf0" id="conf-d" d="M129.9,176.1l-5.7,1.3c-1.6,0.4-2.2,2.3-1.1,3.5l3.8,4.2c1.1,1.2,3.1,0.8,3.6-0.7l1.9-5.5
            C132.9,177.3,131.5,175.7,129.9,176.1z"/>
        <path class="conf6" id="conf-b" d="M284.5,170.7l-5.4,1.2c-1.5,0.3-2.1,2.2-1,3.3l3.6,3.9c1,1.1,2.9,0.8,3.4-0.7l1.8-5.2
            C287.4,171.9,286.1,170.4,284.5,170.7z"/>
        <circle class="conf6" id="conf-c"cx="206.7" cy="144.4" r="4.5"/>
        <path class="conf2" id="conf-c" d="M176.4,192.3h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
            C179.3,191,178,192.3,176.4,192.3z"/>
        <path class="conf2" id="conf-b" d="M263.7,197.4h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
            C266.5,196.1,265.2,197.4,263.7,197.4z"/>
          <!-- yellow-strip-1-->
         <path id="yellow-strip" d="M179.7,102.4c0,0,6.6,15.3-2.3,25c-8.9,9.7-24.5,9.7-29.7,15.6c-5.2,5.9-0.7,18.6,3.7,28.2
            c4.5,9.7,2.2,23-10.4,28.2"/>
        <path class="conf8" id="yellow-strip" d="M252.2,156.1c0,0-16.9-3.5-28.8,2.4c-11.9,5.9-14.9,17.8-16.4,29c-1.5,11.1-4.3,28.8-31.5,33.4"/>
        <path class="conf0" id="conf-a" d="M277.5,254.8h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
            C280.4,253.5,279.1,254.8,277.5,254.8z"/>
        <path class="conf3" id="conf-c" d="M215.2,121.3L215.2,121.3c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3l0,0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7v0
            c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2l0,0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0h0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2v0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7l0,0
            c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1v0C212.5,119.8,214.5,119.8,215.2,121.3z"/>
        <path class="conf3" id="conf-b" d="M224.5,191.7L224.5,191.7c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3v0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7l0,0
            c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2h0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0l0,0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2l0,0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7v0
            c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1l0,0C221.7,190.2,223.8,190.2,224.5,191.7z"/>
        <path class="conf3" id="conf-a" d="M312.6,242.1L312.6,242.1c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3l0,0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7v0
            c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2l0,0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0h0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2v0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7l0,0
            c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1v0C309.9,240.6,311.9,240.6,312.6,242.1z"/>
        <path class="conf8" id="yellow-strip" d="M290.7,215.4c0,0-14.4-3.4-22.6,2.7c-8.2,6.2-8.2,23.3-17.1,29.4c-8.9,6.2-19.8-2.7-32.2-4.1
            c-12.3-1.4-19.2,5.5-20.5,10.9"/>

</svg>
```

это пример анимации текстового восторга Facebook:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Why svg animation is not displaying button click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46707670/7394871) от участника  [@core114](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8268644/core114).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/46707670/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Это то, что вы хотели?

1. Мы начинаем с SVG, скрытого с помощью `display: none`..
2. Когда вы нажимаете на кнопку, мы добавляем класс `show` в SVG. Это изменяет свойство отображения на блокирование. Делаем SVG видимым.
3. Мы также настроили тайм-аут, используя `window.setTimeout()`. Через несколько секунд он перенаправляет на другую страницу, установив `window.location.href`.

```js
var addScoreButton = document.getElementById("add-score-button");
var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");


addScoreButton.addEventListener("click", addScoreClick);


function addScoreClick(evt)
{
  mysvg.classList.add("show");
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.alert("Redirecting to Google");
    //window.location.href="https://www.google.com";
  }, 3600);
}
```

```css
svg {
  display: none;
}

svg.show {
  display: block;
}


.conf0{fill:#FC6394;}
.conf1{fill:#EF3C8A;}
.conf2{fill:#5ADAEA;}
.conf3{fill:#974CBE;}
.conf4{fill:#3CBECD;}
.conf5{fill:#813BBE;}
.conf6{fill:#F9B732;}
.conf7{display:none;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.conf8{fill:none;stroke:#F9B732;stroke-width:9;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}


.confetti-cone {
  transform-origin: 200px 50px;
  animation:confetti-cone1 1.2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes confetti-cone1{
  0%{
    transform:translate(40px, 95px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  15%{
    transform:translate(10px, 145px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1.1, 0.85);

  }
  100%{
    transform:translate(40px, 105px)  rotate(45deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
}

#yellow-strip {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#F9B732;
  stroke-width:9;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  animation: confdash 1.2s ease infinite;
}


@keyframes confdash {
  0%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(-30px, 30px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  2%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(-30px, 30px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  35%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:900;
    transform:translate(-2px, 0px);
    opacity:1;
  }

  85%{
    stroke-dasharray:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    transform:translate(1px, -5px);
    opacity:1;
  }
  90%{
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    transform:translate(2px, -8px);
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    stroke-dashoffset:500;
    transform:translate(2px, -8px);
    opacity:0;
  }
}



#conf-a{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confa 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confa {
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  15%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(25px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  80%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(33px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(37px, -23px) scale(0.5)rotate(230deg);
  }
}


#conf-b{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confb 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confb {
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  12%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(25px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(33px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(37px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(240deg);
  }
}

#conf-c{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confc 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confc {
  0%{
    opacity:0.7;
    transform: translate(-30px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  18%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(5px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(13px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(17px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(230deg);
  }
}

#conf-d{
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: confd 1.2s ease-out infinite;
}
@keyframes confd {
  0%{
    opacity:0.7;
    transform: translate(-20px, 20px) rotate(0);
  }
  18%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(-5px, -10px) rotate(60deg);
  }
  76%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(-8px, -18px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
    transform: translate(-10px, -23px) scale(0.5) rotate(230deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="footer-tab">
  <!--button-->
  <div class="crtnewgrp-btn">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="p-2"><button type="button" id="add-score-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Add score</button></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!--/button-->
</div>

<svg id="mysvg"
     version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 1200 800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 800;" xml:space="preserve">
         <g class="confetti-cone">
             <path class="conf0" d="M131.5,172.6L196,343c2.3,6.1,11,6.1,13.4,0l65.5-170.7L131.5,172.6z"/>
             <path class="conf1" d="M131.5,172.6L196,343c2.3,6.1,11,6.1,13.4,0l6.7-17.5l-53.6-152.9L131.5,172.6z"/>

                <path class="conf2" d="M274.2,184.2c-1.8,1.8-4.2,2.9-7,2.9l-129.5,0.4c-5.4,0-9.8-4.4-9.8-9.8c0-5.4,4.4-9.8,9.9-9.9l129.5-0.4
                    c5.4,0,9.8,4.4,9.8,9.8C277,180,275.9,182.5,274.2,184.2z"/>
                <polygon class="conf3" points="231.5,285.4 174.2,285.5 143.8,205.1 262.7,204.7          "/>
                <path class="conf4" d="M166.3,187.4l-28.6,0.1c-5.4,0-9.8-4.4-9.8-9.8c0-5.4,4.4-9.8,9.9-9.9l24.1-0.1c0,0-2.6,5-1.3,10.6
                    C161.8,183.7,166.3,187.4,166.3,187.4z"/>
                <ellipse transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -89.8523 231.0278)" class="conf2" cx="233.9" cy="224" rx="5.6" ry="5.6"/>
                <path class="conf5" d="M143.8,205.1l5.4,14.3c6.8-2.1,14.4-0.5,19.7,4.8c7.7,7.7,7.6,20.1-0.1,27.8c-1.7,1.7-3.7,3-5.8,4l11.1,29.4
                    l27.7,0l-28-80.5L143.8,205.1z"/>
                <path class="conf2" d="M169,224.2c-5.3-5.3-13-6.9-19.7-4.8l13.9,36.7c2.1-1,4.1-2.3,5.8-4C176.6,244.4,176.6,231.9,169,224.2z"/>
                <ellipse transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -119.0946 221.1253)" class="conf6" cx="207.4" cy="254.3" rx="11.3" ry="11.2"/>
        </g>

            <rect x="113.7" y="135.7" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -99.5348 209.1582)" class="conf7" width="178" height="178"/>
        <line class="conf7" x1="76.8" y1="224.7" x2="328.6" y2="224.7"/>
        <polyline class="conf7" points="202.7,350.6 202.7,167.5 202.7,98.9  "/>
          <!-- here comes the confettis-->

        <circle class="conf2" id="conf-b" cx="195.2" cy="232.6" r="5.1"/>
        <circle class="conf0" id="conf-b" cx="230.8" cy="219.8" r="5.4"/>
        <circle class="conf0" id="conf-c" cx="178.9" cy="160.4" r="4.2"/>
        <circle class="conf6" id="conf-d"cx="132.8" cy="123.6" r="5.4"/>
        <circle class="conf0" id="conf-d" cx="151.9" cy="105.1" r="5.4"/>

        <path class="conf0" id="conf-d" d="M129.9,176.1l-5.7,1.3c-1.6,0.4-2.2,2.3-1.1,3.5l3.8,4.2c1.1,1.2,3.1,0.8,3.6-0.7l1.9-5.5
            C132.9,177.3,131.5,175.7,129.9,176.1z"/>
        <path class="conf6" id="conf-b" d="M284.5,170.7l-5.4,1.2c-1.5,0.3-2.1,2.2-1,3.3l3.6,3.9c1,1.1,2.9,0.8,3.4-0.7l1.8-5.2
            C287.4,171.9,286.1,170.4,284.5,170.7z"/>
        <circle class="conf6" id="conf-c"cx="206.7" cy="144.4" r="4.5"/>
        <path class="conf2" id="conf-c" d="M176.4,192.3h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
            C179.3,191,178,192.3,176.4,192.3z"/>
        <path class="conf2" id="conf-b" d="M263.7,197.4h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
            C266.5,196.1,265.2,197.4,263.7,197.4z"/>
          <!-- yellow-strip-1-->
         <path id="yellow-strip" d="M179.7,102.4c0,0,6.6,15.3-2.3,25c-8.9,9.7-24.5,9.7-29.7,15.6c-5.2,5.9-0.7,18.6,3.7,28.2
            c4.5,9.7,2.2,23-10.4,28.2"/>
        <path class="conf8" id="yellow-strip" d="M252.2,156.1c0,0-16.9-3.5-28.8,2.4c-11.9,5.9-14.9,17.8-16.4,29c-1.5,11.1-4.3,28.8-31.5,33.4"/>
        <path class="conf0" id="conf-a" d="M277.5,254.8h-3.2c-1.6,0-2.9-1.3-2.9-2.9v-3.2c0-1.6,1.3-2.9,2.9-2.9h3.2c1.6,0,2.9,1.3,2.9,2.9v3.2
            C280.4,253.5,279.1,254.8,277.5,254.8z"/>
        <path class="conf3" id="conf-c" d="M215.2,121.3L215.2,121.3c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3l0,0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7v0
            c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2l0,0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0h0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2v0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7l0,0
            c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1v0C212.5,119.8,214.5,119.8,215.2,121.3z"/>
        <path class="conf3" id="conf-b" d="M224.5,191.7L224.5,191.7c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3v0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7l0,0
            c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2h0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0l0,0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2l0,0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7v0
            c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1l0,0C221.7,190.2,223.8,190.2,224.5,191.7z"/>
        <path class="conf3" id="conf-a" d="M312.6,242.1L312.6,242.1c0.3,0.6,0.8,1,1.5,1.1l0,0c1.6,0.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,3.3l0,0c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1.1-0.6,1.7v0
            c0.3,1.6-1.4,2.8-2.8,2l0,0c-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.3-1.8,0h0c-1.4,0.7-3.1-0.5-2.8-2v0c0.1-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.6-1.7l0,0
            c-1.1-1.1-0.5-3.1,1.1-3.3l0,0c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.5,1.5-1.1v0C309.9,240.6,311.9,240.6,312.6,242.1z"/>
        <path class="conf8" id="yellow-strip" d="M290.7,215.4c0,0-14.4-3.4-22.6,2.7c-8.2,6.2-8.2,23.3-17.1,29.4c-8.9,6.2-19.8-2.7-32.2-4.1
            c-12.3-1.4-19.2,5.5-20.5,10.9"/>

</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46776929/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>